Plotting signal to noise ration (SNR) in SPICE softwares
I want to plot SNR in TINA TI software, do you have an idea how can I plot do it?
In this software I just have access to total noise plot and data as follows: (what would be the relationship between total noise and SNR?)


I think you should instead plot the y axis in dB volts to get a better idea. Then it should be fairly straightforward to solve.

Where did this plot come from? As it stands, I'm unable to decipher what it is conveying since the y-axis is total noise which implies a bandwidth of some sort. You would probably need to export power spectral density to a maths program to work out total noise in the bandwidth of the circuit.

@qrk this is the output plot from noise analysis by TINA TI software from Texas Instrument. In fact we have total noise in voltage, what would be formulate? converting total noise in voltage to SNR?

@Andromeda There is a discussion on a TI forum that should help you out.

What you must do is using the definition of the signal-to-noise ratio!

In addition to the noise you show, you also have to compute the signal (probably you can do that with the same circuit you already have by adding the correct input signal and giving the simulator the appropriate instructions.
For the noise plot you already have, you still have to find out whether this is is the noise per unit bandwidth (in 1 Hertz bandwidth, usually called "Volts per square-root Hertz") or it is in some other way defined.
you will have to scale this computed noise to the bandwidth that you actually are using, by multiplying the 1Hz-bandwidth noise voltage by the square root of your bandwidth.
Then you can divide the signal that you have computed by the noise voltage. Possibly converting it to dB (with dB20, since it is voltage).

NB: If you (also) need noise figure or noise factor of the circuit, then some other steps are needed. Here I assume that you just do have one specific signal for which the SNR is to be computed. To be honest, it is often easier to first compute the noise figure and then derive from that what the SNR for any signal will be. But your question seems to be about directly computing the SNR.

I just learned how to plot SNR in TINA TI software, when choosing the noise analysis in the software, we need to enable SNR as well:

Then we can plot SNR as follows:

Reference: https://www.ti.com/tool/TINA-TI
